# J2ME change icon

Tags: java, java-me

Hello is there a way to change the icon of a J2ME application while on the background to do some sort of notification. I am trying to achieve something similar to what de BBChat does on the BlackBerry devices. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To change the icon J2ME application  set MIDlet-Icon property in JAD file
for example

```
MIDlet-Icon: /com/abc/icons/iconfile.png
```

And can you explain

> something similar to what de BBChat
>   does on the BlackBerry devices

Comment: Thank you very much. What I mean is to change the icon while the application is running. Thanks again.

Comment: The application you are talking about BBCChat is written in J2ME?